# IOS: ETIndicatorView don't work fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm using this control in my app, [this](https://github.com/EugeneTrapeznikov/ETActivityIndicatorView)!

I import in my project the ETActivityIndicatorView.h, ETActivityIndicatorView.m, Circle.h and Circle.m and I do:

```
ETActivityIndicatorView *etActivity = [[ETActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((10, 10, 60, 60)];
[etActivity startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:etActivity];
```

The problem is that in the simulator it work fine and I can see the animation, but on my device I see only a little point that don't move itself.
What's the problem? thanks

Comment: Is your device and the simulator the same iOS version? what version?

Comment: Consider use: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD instead... it's much better...\

Comment: I know MBProgressHUD but there is not this type of animation

Comment: What is your background

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute in main queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   ETActivityIndicatorView *etActivity = [[ETActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((10, 10, 60, 60)];
   [etActivity startAnimating];
   [self.view addSubview:etActivity];
});
```

Comment: What is your background, just try to download and run that sample from github and if still you are not able to get your solution, report a bug

Comment: the absurd is that if I download and execute the example from github it work on my device but if I import the 4 classes in my project it work fine only in the simulator